# Capture repeated groups in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a mail log file, which is like this:

```
Aug 15 00:01:06 **** sm-mta*** to=<user1@gmail.com>,<user2@yahoo.com>,user3@aol.com, some_more_stuff
Aug 16 13:16:09 **** sendmail*** to=<user4@yahoo.com>, some_more_stuff
Aug 17 11:14:48 **** sm-mta*** to=<user5@gmail.com>,<user6@gmail.com>, some_more_stuff
```

What I want is a list of all mail hosts in lines that contain "sm-mta". In this case that would be: `['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'aol.com', 'gmail.com', gmail.com']`

`re.findall(r'sm-mta.*to=.+?@(.*?)[>, ]')` will return only first host of each matching line (`['gmail.com','gmail.com']`)

`re.findall(r'.+?@(.*?)[>, ]')` will return the correct list, but I need filtering too. Is there any workaround on this?

Comment: You can try this one https://eval.in/875159

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot use PyPi regex library, you will have to do that in two steps: 1) grab the lines with `sm-mta` and 2) grab the values you need, with something like

import re

```
txt="""Aug 15 00:01:06 **** sm-mta*** to=<user1@gmail.com>,<user2@yahoo.com>,user3@aol.com, some_more_stuff
Aug 16 13:16:09 **** sendmail*** to=<user4@yahoo.com>, some_more_stuff
Aug 17 11:14:48 **** sm-mta*** to=<user5@gmail.com>,<user6@gmail.com>, some_more_stuff"""
rx = r'@([^\s>,]+)'
filtered_lines = [x for x in txt.split('\n') if 'sm-mta' in x]
print(re.findall(rx, " ".join(filtered_lines)))
```

See the [Python demo online](http://rextester.com/UNCDS25656). The `@([^\s>,]+)` pattern will match `@` and will capture and return any 1+ chars other than whitespace, `>` and `,`.

If you can use PyPi regex library, you may get the list of the strings you need with

```
>>> import regex
>>> x="""Aug 15 00:01:06 **** sm-mta*** to=<user1@gmail.com>,<user2@yahoo.com>,user3@aol.com, some_more_stuff
Aug 16 13:16:09 **** sendmail*** to=<user4@yahoo.com>, some_more_stuff
Aug 17 11:14:48 **** sm-mta*** to=<user5@gmail.com>,<user6@gmail.com>, some_more_stuff"""
>>> rx = r'(?:^(?=.*sm-mta)|\G(?!^)).*?@\K[^\s>,]+'
>>> print(regex.findall(rx, x, regex.M))
['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'aol.com,', 'gmail.com', 'gmail.com']
```

See [the Python online demo](http://rextester.com/AYSEK11532) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LIfuj5/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(?:^(?=.*sm-mta)|\G(?!^))` - a line that has `sm-mta` substring after any 0+ chars other than line break chars, or the place where the previous match ended
- `.*?@` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the `@` and a `@` itself
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all the text matched so far in the current iteration
- `[^\s>,]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace, `,` and `>`

Answer (score 2):

Try `regex` module.

```
x="""Aug 15 00:01:06 **** sm-mta*** to=<user1@gmail.com>,<user2@yahoo.com>,user3@aol.com, some_more_stuff
Aug 16 13:16:09 **** sendmail*** to=<user4@yahoo.com>, some_more_stuff
Aug 17 11:14:48 **** sm-mta*** to=<user5@gmail.com>,<user6@gmail.com>, some_more_stuff"""
import regex
print regex.findall(r"sm-mta.*to=\K|\G(?!^).+?@(.*?)[>, ]", x, version=regex.V1)
```

Output:
`['', 'gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'aol.com', '', 'gmail.com', 'gmail.com']`

Just ignore the first empty match.

https://regex101.com/r/7zPc6j/1